# I have a question about if else statements and raw_input statements

Tags: python, if-statement

So my code isn't working, and just skipping straight to the else statement no matter what input the user uses.

```
start_over = 10

STONKS = raw_input("YESN'T? ")

if raw_input == "What?":
        start_over -= 1 
        print STONKS    
elif raw_input == "Yeah?":
        print "Nah, don't be a bully Ninja"
        start_over -=1
        print STONKS     
else:
        print "YOU ATE MY BEANS?!"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `raw_input`?

Comment: `raw_input` is a function, **not the result of that function**. The result was assigned to the `STONKS` variable. Look carefully at your `if` test to see where you went wrong there.

Comment: I could just write a quick answer but instead I think there is a chance here for you to learn a bit more about python.  What do you think the value of `raw_input` is here?  It's a variable but are you ever actually setting it?  If you looks at Python documentation, `raw_input` is a method to pull in input from the user and store it in a variable, in this case, `STONKS`.  So instead of comparing the `raw_input` variable that doesn't exist, you need to compare your different cases to `STONKS`.  Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare against `STONKS` and not `raw_input`

```
start_over = 10

STONKS = raw_input("YESN'T? ")

if STONKS == "What?":
    start_over -= 1 
        print STONKS    
elif STONKS == "Yeah?":
    print "Nah, don't be a bully Ninja"
    start_over -=1
    print STONKS     
else:
    print "YOU ATE MY BEANS?!"
```